# How to make custom colored paper

Tags: paper

I love making a craft made from paper. Currently I have difficulty to find colour specific paper such Teal coloured paper. I expect I will get the same issue when I need specific coloured paper since I have my favourite colours got from my Pantone colour sheet and I want to use some of their colours.

Is there a way to dye paper and get the near-accurate result?

**im going to use it for origami**

Answer (score 3):

You can create colored paper pulp by running colored craft paper through a blender. An alternative is to add food color or paint (or tea, or any other stain or coloring agent) to white paper pulp. Once you have several jars with different colored pulps, you can then blend those colors together to make the color you desire to use in your paper. The final color of the pulp will shift slightly as it dries when you make the paper, sort of like the shift in color between wet and dry paint. Some practice is needed to get the precise final color you desire.

The following video shows how to mix colored paperpulp when making paper:
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCjLGX6W48Q

Comment: This will produce a soft, thick, rough-finished paper, generally.  There are paper crafts that depend on color that can't use paper of this kind (rosemaling, origami, probably others) -- but for those that can, this gives the most control over color and texture.

Comment: Im going to use it for origami.

Answer (score 0):

I have dyed fabric before, using store-bought fabric dyes.  I imagine you could immerse a sheet of paper in a bath of fabric dye for a minute, then let it "drip dry" by hanging it (with an old towel underneath to catch the drips!!), and finally iron it with a cool iron to keep the paper flat. You As with Mark Ripley's earlier answer, you would need to experiment with mixing fabric dyes together to get the colors you want -- but you would have a LOT of control over the colors you end up with! And obviously you can experiment with postage-stamp sized swatches of the paper that you'll ultimately use.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make custom paper with Pantone colours is to contact Pantone for the colourant you want.

Pantone™ Corporation makes inks, dyes, colourants, and finishes for paper, paint, cloth, ceramics, and other applications.

Add the desired pigment to your recipe for the desired effect.

You can contact them directly through their web site.

EDIT: If you know the exact Pantone Colour Number and Pantone makes paper in that colour, shred the pantone paper and use it to make the pulp for the paper you (re) make.